# Need to validate form before sending

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to send a form to email but I wanted the name field to be validated (if no content then don't send)
I cannot get it validate and then end through the php script I have working correctly
[I have created a jsfiddle at the following link](http://jsfiddle.net/4TuVU/4/)
Can someone help please?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.form-horizontal').on('submit', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if (!name) {
        showError();
    }
    else {
        $('#contact-form').submit();
    }

});

function showError() {

    $('.tyler-error').show();
}

});
```

Comment: "I cannot get it working." Go on...

Comment: Never depend on client-side validation. Regardless of whether you get this working or not, you STILL have to validate on the server.

Comment: You forgot to select jquery library in the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/4TuVU/4/

Comment: Even with the library added, the button seems to be inactive when there is text in the field I want validated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fhj4J/)

In your fiddle, you didn't select jQuery from the library dropdown.

Secondly, you should avoid submitting the form from within the submit handler, instead just preventDefault if there is a validation error.

```
$('.form-horizontal').on('submit', function (e) {
    var name = $('#name').val();
    if (!name) {
        showError();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

If you really want to keep the code as it was, you need to call the forms submit function, not the jQuery submit function:

```
$('#contact-form')[0].submit();
// or
$('#contact-form').get(0).submit();
```

Here, `[0]` or `.get(0)` is giving you the plain JavaScript DOM element with no jQuery wrapper, and with this you can call `submit()`.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 provides input validation, you can set  in order to tell the browser that your html view is HTML5.

```
//Set your doctype for HTML5.
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="the_form">
        //here html5 will not submit if the box is empty or does not meet the email
        //addres format.
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email..">
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

If you dont want to use HTML5, you could also make a simple javascript code to not submit if the input is empty.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = init();

    function init(){
        //get form.
        var form = document.getElementById("the_form");

        form.onsubmit = email_validation;
    }

    function email_validation(){
        email = document.getElementById("email");

        if(email.value == ''){
            //return false to avoid submission.

            return false;
        }
        else{
            //do whatever code.
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="the_form">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter email..">
        <input type="submit" value="send">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

with this way, your email will be validated before is sent, hope this work for you.